# how to use is_srvrolemember to list all server roles of a user

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2016, role, trace

For dealing with server permissions I am currently using 
 a procedure called [sp_SrvPermissions V6.0 by Kenneth Fisher](http://www.sqlstudies.com) `thank you Kenneth`, however,

while running a [profile trace](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1035/sql-server-performance-statistics-using-a-server-side-trace/) I often see the following line:

```
select is_srvrolemember('sysadmin') * 1 +
       is_srvrolemember('serveradmin') * 2 +
       is_srvrolemember('setupadmin') * 4 +
       is_srvrolemember('securityadmin') * 8 +
       is_srvrolemember('processadmin') * 16 +
       is_srvrolemember('dbcreator') * 32 +
       is_srvrolemember('diskadmin') * 64 +
       is_srvrolemember('bulkadmin') * 128
```

My question is:

How can I use the above script that uses [is_srvrolemember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/is-srvrolemember-transact-sql) to find out the server roles of `mycompany\myuser`?

Answer (score 1):

The code you saw in profiler has nothing to do with the sp cited.

You can find **explicit** server roles of `mycompany\myuser` using following code:

```
select sp.name 
from sys.server_role_members rm join sys.server_principals sp 
        on rm.role_principal_id = sp.principal_id
where suser_name(member_principal_id) ='mycompany\myuser';
```

What I mean by **explicit** roles: these are roles to which the principal `mycompany\myuser` was added **explicitely**: `exec sys.sp_addsrvrolemember 'mycompany\myuser', 'some_server_role'`.

But your principal is `Windows` principal, this means he can inherit server role membership from different Windows groups of which he is member.

To find out **all the roles** he is member you should impersonate the principal and explore his login tokens:

```
execute as login = 'mycompany\myuser';

select *
from sys.login_token
where type = 'SERVER ROLE';
```

This will give you all the server roles `mycompany\myuser` is member of, those inherited from `Windows groups` included.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can run this.

Let's create a login

```
CREATE LOGIN [roletest] WITH PASSWORD=N'roletest', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
```

Make the login member of 3 server role.

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE [setupadmin] ADD MEMBER [roletest]
GO

ALTER SERVER ROLE [diskadmin] ADD MEMBER [roletest]
GO

ALTER SERVER ROLE [dbcreator] ADD MEMBER [roletest]
GO
```

Now if you are not logged in as `roletest`, you can run following.

```
select is_srvrolemember('sysadmin','roletest') * 1 +
       is_srvrolemember('serveradmin','roletest') * 2 +
       is_srvrolemember('setupadmin','roletest') * 4 +
       is_srvrolemember('securityadmin','roletest') * 8 +
       is_srvrolemember('processadmin','roletest') * 16 +
       is_srvrolemember('dbcreator','roletest') * 32 +
       is_srvrolemember('diskadmin','roletest') * 64 +
       is_srvrolemember('bulkadmin','roletest') * 128
```

You will get an answer of 100. There is only one combination possible to get 100.

setupadmin (4)+ dbcreator(32)+diskadmin(64)= 100

If you are logged in as `roletest` you can use following syntax. Because `login` is an optional parameter.

> ' login '
>
> Is the name of the SQL Server login to check. login is
>   sysname, with a default of NULL. If no value is specified, the result
>   is based on the current Execution context. If the parameter contains
>   the word NULL will return NULL.

```
select is_srvrolemember('sysadmin') * 1 +
       is_srvrolemember('serveradmin') * 2 +
       is_srvrolemember('setupadmin') * 4 +
       is_srvrolemember('securityadmin') * 8 +
       is_srvrolemember('processadmin') * 16 +
       is_srvrolemember('dbcreator') * 32 +
       is_srvrolemember('diskadmin') * 64 +
       is_srvrolemember('bulkadmin') * 128
```

If you do not want to match the numbers other option is to run something like below for each role.

```
IF IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('diskadmin','roletest') = 1
   print 'roletest login is a member of the diskadmin role'
ELSE IF IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('diskadmin','roletest') = 0
   print 'roletest login is NOT a member of the diskadmin role'
ELSE IF IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('diskadmin','roletest') IS NULL
   print 'ERROR: Invalid server role specified'
```